# Why does it display Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin only in mobile web browsers?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, cors

In my spring-boot+React app working fine on the desktop web browser, but when I create a record through a mobile(I used iPhone) web browser like chrome or safari, it shows 'Origin 'http://www.example.com' is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.I have already added 'Cors Mappings' like

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/brands/**", "/api/users/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js"
                        ) .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                        .permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/brands/**").permitAll()      
                        .antMatchers("/api/familys/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/models/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated();

           http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
           }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove *WebMvcConfig class* and add a bean called corsConfigurationSource in your *SecurityConfig class* which will be able to set headers/methods and allow any origins using "*" but if you want to allow a specific origin, you can add it.

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to change the return type of the method? Because 'source' is in UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource  type. And also, I need to add this bean to SecurityConfig class, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. you need to add this bean in SecurityConfig class. you don't need to change something within this bean..

Comment: But it asks to change the return type into 'UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource'

Comment: Nope because UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource class implements CorsConfigurationSource that is an interface, so it's no problem about it  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.html

Comment: yes, you are correct.No need to change the return type. However, I tried putting the given bean to SecurityConfig class. But, still getting the same error on the mobile web browser.

Comment: Yes, In my computer web browser it is working fine.I’m able to create records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186251/discussion-between-jonathan-johx-and-chk-buddi).

Comment: Not yet I’m troubleshooting them

Comment: I’ve noticed that this error come only creating records with image